# Missing comments

Tags: support, status-bydesign

I am sure I commented on [Is extremely young meat indigestible?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/22581/is-extremely-young-meat-indigestible) but now nothing is showing. How does that happen?

Answer (score 1):

The post on which the comments were added was deleted by the author.

He edited most of the content of that answer into the original question, so he probably felt that the answer was no longer necessary/relevant.

You can view deleted posts [if you have enough reputation](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/privileges/moderator-tools) (10k).

Comment: Ahhh is that what happened, thanks. 10K that's a lot of cooking!!!